# Moving Platform object - Android game using box2D

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I have a 2D Side scrolling android game under development, using And Engine.

And Engine uses the BOX2D physics engine.

In my game I have an object called "moving platform". It's a simple platform, which is moving in right/left direction and constantly change its moving direction depending on its current X coordinate. It works fine and I'm moving it using:

```
    body.setLinearVelocity(-1 * 5, b.getLinearVelocity().y);
```

Now my problem is: obviously the player may try to jump on this moving platform to move with it, but unfortunately player will fall down if he doesn't move with this platform.

I'm trying to make it like in most platform games, where if the player is on the platform, the player moves with the platform by itself (so you are not forced to keep trying to stay on this platform to avoid falling down).

So far I have tried or have been thinking about:

- in contact listener check if player's body is touching platform's body, and if yes apply current platform linear velocity to player
- increase friction of the platform

Without success so far, I would be grateful for some ideas/tips. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of a game which uses what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for answer, for example take a look at this image found on google from mario game (ignore those red arrows, its screen found on google) http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Y634Kn9fsds/TCiXBAIvlxI/AAAAAAAAABA/-Fum-bwdFhQ/s1600/mario1.jpg

As you can see mario is currently staying on the object which I call moving platform, because its moving in left/right direction. I have the same, but when player is staying on my platform, he has to keep moving, otherwise he will fall down.

Comment: I thought your problem was something else, but I think my answer will solve your problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the platform's friction coefficient is one, the player should not be able to have a relative velocity to it's velocity. So just set `1f` as the friction field of the moving platform `FixtureDef`.

If this doesn't work, make sure you didn't pass `0` as the density when creating the player fixture def, because kinematic friction is calculated as: `friction=(friction coefficient)*(normal force)` then a body without mass (density = 0), in most of the cases (Your is included in "most"), will have *no* friction.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did like you said, set 1f in platform's friction while creating fixture_def, and my player's fixture def is

PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0f);

So its like you said, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I set player's friction like 0.01f, and platform's friction at really big value (50000) and in fact it works, player is keep moving along with platform, but he can not move (using controller) of course he may jump and move in the air, but its still bug. I will try to find way how to change dynamically body's friction, because if I would change player's friction back to 0, while player may want to move with controller, it would be perfect.

Comment: If you set even a small friction, it should still be enough to make the player stay on the platform, and yet not enough to negate the force you apply when the player moves

Comment: If this doesn't work too, consider making player movement with `setLinearVelocity` rather than `applyForce`, this way the friction won't stop the player (It will slow it down, though...). Actually, when the player moves it should control it's velocity rather than forces (acceleration)

Comment: I'm moving my player using controller, by using setLinearVelocity from beginning.

Comment: Don't set the friction coefficient to a too high number, otherwise it won't let the player move at all. Try what I suggested in the last 2 comments - put a small friction coefficient and make sure the make the density > 0, that way it should work.

Comment: Lately I gave up with this issue, and started checking it again today. And it works more or less with way you said. So I have changed player's: density:0 elasticity: 0 friction 0.1f And in platform's FixtureDef i set: density: 1 elasticity: 0 and friction > 0 Tested with many values, only with really big ones it prevents player from falling down, but obviously it negate the force you apply when the player moves (player is not able to move, only jump)

Comment: In my last game with Box2D, in order to let the character roll around (It's a circle) I used: `PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.5f)` for the bounds (floor, walls) and `PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1f, 0, 0.5f)` for the player. This works great.